# Achievements dropdown does not recognize unupvotes

Tags: support, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

I had an answer upvoted three times, and +30 showed in the top bar. I looked, and sure enough the dropdown showed that I got +30 rep for [the answer](https://serverfault.com/a/559255/126632).

But a short time later, one of those people unupvoted, leaving the post at +2/-0.

[image: 2 up / 0 down]

Unfortunately, the achievement dropdown still showed +30. No notice was given of the lost reputation.

[image: +30 reputation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a slight delay in the aggregation (usually on the order of seconds), but you'll see it's already updated.

Comment: Yes, it has updated. But where's my red `-10`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton we rollup for the same day, the same as your profile has done for over a year :)

Comment: @NickCraver The profile's reputation view actually separated out read from unread changes for the day.  It takes some getting used to to see them combined.